# Git merge conflicts,unable to push or pull code from master

Tags: github, git-push, git-pull, git-merge-conflict

I’m stuck at this point where me and my teammate working on the master branch and we both pushed the code but I didn’t pull the changes and again pushed the code so here i’m now I can’t pull or push the code.. what should i do?

Comment: What's the output of `git status`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might look intimidating but bare with me:

1. Get the hash of the stable common commit between you and master: `git log`
2. Soft reset your commits to convert them to unstaged changes.
   : `git reset --soft [hash]`
3. Stash you current working changes: `git stash`
4. Fetch latest changes from remote: `git fetch`
5. Pull latest changes from remote: `git pull`
6. Bring back your work from the stash: `git stash apply` or `git stash pop`
7. Resolve any conflicts and recommit your work: `git commit ...`
8. Push your changes to remote: `git push`

From now own, you should remember to do all your work on a separate branch and then merge them onto `master`.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout a new branch.

`git checkout -b tmp`

Delete your current master.

`git branch -D master`

Checkout master from origin

`git checkout master`

Merge your branch and handle conflicts

`git merge tmp`